# How can I use stanford-openIE for Chinese text

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am working on on `Stanford-openIE` but I do not know whether it supports Chinese text or not. If it supports Chinese language, **How can I use `stanford-openIE` for Chinese text?**

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: I see on their website that Stanford's core NLP system offers packaging models in Arabic, Chinese, French, German, and Spanish

Answer (score 0):

Stanford's OpenIE system was developed for English. It's based off of universal dependencies, meaning that in theory it shouldn't be too hard to adapt to other languages; but, nonetheless, it's highly unlikely that it would work out of the box.

At minimum, the [relation triple segmenter](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/naturalli/RelationTripleSegmenter.java) would have to be adapted for Chinese. For some of the more subtle functionality, the code to mark natural logic polarity and the code to score prepositional phrase deletions would have to be rewritten.